# Why ANDROID_HOME path is required Android Linux?

Tags: android, linux

I have one confusion about Android environment variable path. 
As we already are setting tools and platform-tools path for Android SDK. 
So, Why do we require to set ANDROID_HOME path as environment variable ? 
Is it replaced by tools and platform-tools path?

thanks,

Comment: Because some script or tool in the SDK uses paths relative to it, rather than relative to its own location.  Is it really that big a deal?

Answer (score 0):

Some scripts and build tools require access to SDK main path (for example to get platforms folder) and they cant get this path from path environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

**ANDROID_HOME** is usually a directory like .android. Its where things like the Debug Key will be stored.

```
 export ANDROID_HOME=~/.android
```

You can automate it for your login. Just add it to your .bash_profile (below is from my OS X 10.8.5 machine)

```
 $ cat ~/.bash_profile
```

**Android**

```
export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/opt/android-ndk-r9
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/opt/android-sdk
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`
export ANDROID_HOME=~/.android
```